# How create a unmute command similar to my mute command that requires the permissions of a Moderator or Admin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord.js discord bot and I have managed to do the basic Kick, Ban & Warn commands (all of which do log to a channel) but now I'm working on the Mute/Unmute commands, I do have the mute command created but the issue I am having right now is creating the Unmute command in a similar format.

**This is my mute command**

```
if(command === "mute") {
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find('name', 'cgr420-logs');

if (!logchannel) return message.reply('I cannot find a logs channel');
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return 
message.reply(":no_entry_sign: **Error:** You don't have the **Mute Members** 
permission!");
if (reason.length < 1) return message.reply('You must supply a reason for the 
mute.');
if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('You must mention 
someone to mute them.').catch(console.error);

if (!message.guild.member(user).bannable) return 
message.reply(`:no_entry_sign: I cannot mute that member`);
message.guild.member(user).ban();

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor(0xFF0000)
  .setTimestamp()
  .addField('Action:', 'Mute')
  .addField('User:', `${user.username}#${user.discriminator} (${user.id})`)
  .addField('Moderator:', 
  `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
  .addField('Reason', reason);
  message.channel.send(`:hammer: Bippity boppity **MUTED**! I\'ve logged the 
  mute in the logs channel.`)
  return client.channels.get(logchannel.id).send({embed});
  };
```

I would appreciate any form of help in the right direction.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This command is not muting users, it's banning them: `message.guild.member(user).ban();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I mean, you can't unmute users if they're not in the server. You either need a "unban" command or a new mute command.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(command === "unmute") {
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find('name', 'cgr420-logs');
let role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'mute')
//CHANGE THIS ^^

if (!logchannel) return message.reply('I cannot find a logs channel');
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return 
message.reply(":no_entry_sign: **Error:** You don't have the **Mute Members** 
permission!");
if (reason.length < 1) return message.reply('You must supply a reason for the mute.');
if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('You must mention 
someone to mute them.').catch(console.error);

if (!message.guild.member(user).roles.has(role)) return message.reply(`:no_entry_sign: I cannot unmute that member`);
message.guild.member(user).removeRole(role);

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("0xFF0000")
  .setTimestamp()
  .addField('Action:', 'Unmute')
  .addField('User:', `${user.tag} (${user.id})`)
  .addField('Moderator:', 
  `${message.author.tag}`)
  .addField('Reason', reason);
  message.channel.send(`:hammer: Bippity boppity **UNMUTED**! I\'ve logged the 
  unmute in the logs channel.`)
  return logchannel.send(embed);
  };
```

You don’t have to do `client.channels.get(logchannel.id).send()`, you can just do `logchannel.send()`.

I see that you’ve made it ban the member that has to be "unmuted", I’ve made a variable, `mute`, that finds a role named 'mute', you can change it to whatever you’d like. The command removes the `mute` role from the member.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work, I do have Mute Members permissions since I am the owner but the bot seems to think I don't have permission?

It might be just me being dumbfounded or it could be the source.

Answer (score 0):

````
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "mute",
        description: "Mutes a member in the discord!",
        usage: "[name | nickname | mention | ID] <reason> (optional)",
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        try {
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")) return message.channel.send("**You Dont Have Permmissions To Mute Someone! - [MANAGE_GUILD]**");

            if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")) return message.channel.send("**I Don't Have Permissions To Mute Someone! - [MANAGE_GUILD]**")
            if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A User To Be Muted!**");

            var mutee = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(ro => ro.displayName.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
            if (!mutee) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Valid User To Be Muted!**");

            if (mutee === message.member) return message.channel.send("**You Cannot Mute Yourself!**")
            if (mutee.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(message.guild.me.roles.highest) >= 0) return message.channel.send('**Cannot Mute This User!**')

            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            if (mutee.user.bot) return message.channel.send("**Cannot Mute Bots!**");
            const userRoles = mutee.roles.cache
                .filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id)
                .map(r => r.id)

            let muterole;
            let dbmute = await db.fetch(`muterole_${message.guild.id}`);
            let muteerole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "muted")

            if (!message.guild.roles.cache.has(dbmute)) {
                muterole = muteerole
            } else {
                muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(dbmute)
            }

            if (!muterole) {
                try {
                    muterole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                        data: {
                            name: "muted",
                            color: "#514f48",
                            permissions: []
                        }
                    })
                    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel) => {
                        await channel.createOverwrite(muterole, {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                            ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                            SPEAK: false,
                            CONNECT: false,
                        })
                    })
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            };

            if (mutee.roles.cache.has(muterole.id)) return message.channel.send("**User Is Already Muted!**")

            db.set(`muteeid_${message.guild.id}_${mutee.id}`, userRoles)
          try {
            mutee.roles.set([muterole.id]).then(() => {
                mutee.send(`**Hello, You Have Been Muted In ${message.guild.name} for - ${reason || "No Reason"}`).catch(() => null)
            })
            } catch {
                 mutee.roles.set([muterole.id])                               
            }
                if (reason) {
                const sembed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
                    .setDescription(`${mutee.user.username} was successfully muted for ${reason}`)
                message.channel.send(sembed);
                } else {
                    const sembed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .setDescription(`${mutee.user.username} was successfully muted`)
                message.channel.send(sembed2);
                }
            
            let channel = db.fetch(`modlog_${message.guild.id}`)
            if (!channel) return;

            let embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RED')
                .setThumbnail(mutee.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL())
                .addField("**Moderation**", "mute")
                .addField("**Mutee**", mutee.user.username)
                .addField("**Moderator**", message.author.username)
                .addField("**Reason**", `${reason || "**No Reason**"}`)
                .addField("**Date**", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()

            var sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel)
            if (!sChannel) return;
            sChannel.send(embed)
        } catch {
            return;
        }
    }
}```
i want for this anyone tell pls
````